# TextBoxFor vs EditorFor in MVC for date

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

Theres is one thing that anoy me a bit.

In the same page, I bind a date from a database using this :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.dossier_ele.Date_depart, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" )
```

Using the one up here, I can't retreive the value in the controler on postback...

But, if i use the folowing one:

```
@Html.EditorFor(t => t.dossier_ele.Date_depart, new { DisplayMode = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}" })
```

Then all is fine program wise; I retreive my value fine, BUT ! It dosen't format the date here, I would like help for that too if it's possible.

**In fact, I would like, whatever between: the first one post back correctly, or the seconde one format correctly...**

Please notice that the first example is a `TextBoxFor` and the second one is an `EditorFor` and that my var Date_depart is comming from a database so i cannot apply any tag on it... (Can i ?)

In my model, this is the table :

```
public dossiers dossier_ele { get; set; } // I can access in model.dossier_ele.Date_depart
```

`dossiers` it is an entity framework database object containing a lots of fields

Probably not useful but here, my whole model :

```
public class FormulaireMod
{
    DateTime reference = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    public string Fiche { get; set; }

    public E_Ele eleveJade { get; set; }
    public E_Freq Frequentation { get; set; }
    public string Année { get; set; }

    public string tel { get; set; }

    public string user { get; set; }


    public int dos_TypeEntrevu { get; set; }


    public int dos_raisonDepart { get; set; }

    public dossiers dossier_ele { get; set; }

    public ApplicationMVC donneApp { get; set; }

    public suivis suivis_ele { get; set; }

    public dossiers_pro projet_ele { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7462514 Assuming you are in the US, you would have to specify the format as "yyyy-mm-dd" for the default model binding to work for your DateTime model property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What formats does ASP.NET MVC expect for DateTime so that the model binding will work properly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462474/what-formats-does-asp-net-mvc-expect-for-datetime-so-that-the-model-binding-will)

Comment: Please note that in English, the letter I, when referring to yourself, should be capitalized. I had started to edit your question to do that when you edited it for some other reason. Also, punctuation generally comes directly after the preceding word, with no space.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question

Comment: At this point I should just re ask the question and delete this one....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try define your date format in your model.
Like this:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Date_depart{ get; set; }
```

Use `@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.dossier_ele.Date_depart)` in your page.

Comment: I would like to use your tag, but the var Date_depart is comming straight from a database and i don't think i can apply such a tag on an auto generated field

Comment: @Antoine what do you mean coming straight from the database?  `Date_depart` is a property inside a class that represents a table in your database.

Comment: @Antoine post your entire class which holds the property `Date_depart`

Comment: Look even if i send you my whole model there is no Date_depart explicitely defined, do you know entity ?